# PERMISSION_DENIED when invite people to google my business profile account

Tags: permission-denied, google-my-business-api, google-my-business, google-business-profile-api, google-business-profile

I'm trying to use Google API to invite managers to my business profile account
My role is "OWNER" and I try to invite someone by email
I used OAuth playground tool to achieve that.

scope: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage`
method: `POST`
URL: `https://mybusinessaccountmanagement.googleapis.com/v1/accounts/108463676430689610134/admins`

request body:

```
{
  "role": "MANAGER",
  "admin": "mina.zakaria.zakher@gmail.com"
}
```

response body

```
{
  "error": {
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED", 
    "message": "The caller does not have permission", 
    "code": 403
  }
}
```

I don't know why permission denied while I could add the same email using dashboard? any help?

Comment: Can you please verify that the chosen account (=location group) is not actually the PERSONAL account?

Comment: yes it's a personal account. when listing the accounts

{
  "accounts": [
    {
      "vettedState": "NOT_VETTED", 
      "type": "PERSONAL", 
      "name": "accounts/108463676430689610134", 
      "verificationState": "UNVERIFIED", 
      "accountName": "Mina Zakaria"
    }
  ]
}

couldn't I grant access via API to a personal account?

Comment: Please specify how and where you "could add the same email using dashboard", this is not supported for personal accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Inviting others as admins is only supported for accounts that are not of AccountType PERSONAL.

Personal account:

[image: Personal account]

Location group account (where a user could invite others via the group settings capability):

[image: Location group account]